# How to get the name of a Java program?

Tags: java

I'm creating an application that could be either an `.exe` or a `.jar` and I need to know which it is. Does anyone know how I can get the file name/extension of a program running in Java please? I can get the path of the program running but I can't get the name.

Comment: The question is unclear. Process A is launched via a launcher (.exe or .jar) do you want to find out the details of the launcher in process A or in some other process B. What is java based? process A or process B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make 'name of program' a property that is passed to your program via '-D' command-line switch, like so

```
java -Dprogram.name=myApp.jar -jar myApp.jar
```

Read it in your code like so

```
if ("myApp.jar".equals(System.getProperty("program.name"))) {
   // perform appropriate actions...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've commented above in regards to your answer aswell!

Answer (score 5):

The actual program running the JAR file would be `java.exe`.

I suggest you approach the problem from a completely different angle and have the exe wrapper set a system property that the program queries. Or you could have it and the JAR manifest specify different main classes.

Comment: Hi, now I see the implication - thank you for your reply. I will try what you have suggested but I will find a work around somehow!

Answer (score 0):

This snippet below should do the trick:

```
try {
    Class cls = Class.forName(getClass().getCanonicalName());
    ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
    String nomeDaClasse=cls.getCanonicalName().replace(".", "/").concat(".class");
    System.out.println("nomeDaClasse = "+ nomeDaClasse);
    String urlClasseJava = cLoader.getSystemResource(nomeDaClasse).toString();
    _nomeArquivoJava=urlClasseJava.substring("jar:file:".length(), urlClasseJava.indexOf("!/"));
    System.out.println("_nomeArquivoJava = "+ _nomeArquivoJava);  
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
$ java -jar CasaInformatizada-0.1.4.jar  
dez 03, 2020 5:27:49 PM br.com.cvra.monitorArduino.Principal subirEscrivao
INFORMAÇÕES: /var/tmp/monitorArduino.xml
nomeDaClasse = br/com/cvra/monitorArduino/Principal.class
_nomeArquivoJava = /var/tmp/CasaInformatizada-0.1.4.jar
```

This is based upon the follow sources:

> https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077485/java-tip-120--execute-self-extracting-jars.html
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/classloader_getsystemresource.htm

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it. Also, please explain where the links go to, how they relate to the question, and how they help.

Comment: The snippet retrieves the path of the jar file which is running it. It works using the classLoader of the class instantiated by String, then using the full name of the class, with periods replaced by foward slashes, and adding ".class" to makes the class file name that is used to get the absolute path of the file running the application. The links go to an article about jar files (the first) and to a open reference about classLoader (the second), handling different parts of the snippet suggested, and giving more details about each one of it's original parts to complete the understanding.